# Are there any Windows text editors that allow you to scroll through a directory?

Tags: windows, text-editor

Perhaps related to [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26193/what-text-editors-let-you-view-and-edit-multiple-files-in-a-single-long-page-si) but slightly different.  If I have a directory of images, there are certain programs which let you do say left arrow or right arrow to quickly scroll through the images.  Well I want the same thing in Windows with text files.  Something which does not open a new tab or new application with each file, but which allows with say a single tab the user to quickly view the .txt files (or perhaps some other filter) in a scroll fashion such that only one file's contents are ever displayed on the screen at once.

Are there any programs that meet these requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I use the built-in feature of Windows called "Preview pane". You can scroll through the files using up and down arrows in detailed view.

[image: Windows file preview]

Comment: Clever trick, but with its limitations.  One difficulty is a good number of my text files actually have no extension which poses a problem for the preview pane.  If I mass rename them then they all do get previewed.  Let's see how far I can get with this one.

Comment: @demongolem: ok, now I understand a bit better why you wanted to filter for file extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Total Commander** (it is shareware) with plugins for QuickView mode. Example of quickview plugin for images: **[Imagine](http://totalcmd.net/plugring/imagine.html)**. Activate quickview by Ctrl+Q and second pane will show images then (if Imagine was installed).

Analog which is free: **Unreal Commander** (it is not updated for long).

Comment: Yes I see Quick View Panel works in a similar fashion to Windows explorer for Total Commander on the directory I am testing.  The only thing I would have to say (which is only tangentially related to the question) is that there are so many unique menu items there would seem to be a bit of a learning curve using that product.

Comment: But it is still good for going thru a directory.